# nano editor does not remember last editing position

Tags: macos, nano

I have previously used the `nano` editor under Cygwin/Windows. When I invoked `nano` with

```
nano FILENAME
```

and I had edited the file before already with nano, the cursor was placed at the last known position.

Now I'm on MacOS (its version identifies itself as *PICO 5.09*) and found that `nano` does not remember its position anymore. Is this something which can be configured somehow, or is it just the difference in implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note by the way, `nano` on macOS isn't the real `nano`, it's simply the `pico` text editor that has an alias (a shortcut using a *symlink*, so that people used to use the `nano` text editor get to a text editor...)

Since macOS 12.3 Apple replaced `nano` with `pico`.

`pico` is, sort-of, the predecessor of `nano` and doesn't have a lot of it's more powerful functionality, including remembering the position.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following your information, I found [this](https://osxdaily.com/2022/03/27/get-nano-text-editor-mac/) page, which shows how to bring the "original" nano to MacOS. I'll try to follow this road.

Comment: Great, let us know how it goes with it. (I saw that, but wasn't sure if I should recommend using Homebrew.)

Comment: Indeed, Homebrew installs nano. There are still minor problems with this, but I will post them in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Nano editor remember the last editing position on macOS, you need to create a configuration file for it. These are the steps:

1. Open your terminal and type `nano ~/.nanorc` to create or open the Nano configuration file.
2. Add the following line at the end of the file: `set positionlog`
3. Save the file by pressing **Ctrl+O** and then exit Nano by pressing **Ctrl+X**.

Now when you reopen Nano, it should remember the last editing position. If it doesn't work, try restarting your terminal or computer.

Comment: I already **did** have `postionlog` turned on, but this was ignored by the original `nano` which comes with the Mac. See the accepted answer above, how I could solve the problem.